# Nao Robot unresponsive on boot

Tags: nao-robot

Recently I acquired a V6 Nao robot, got it all set up without any issues, was able to work on the robot then powered it off, but this morning when powering the robot on it seems to fail to boot, it doesn't make the usual "oh" then stand up.

No leds lit and when you click the chest button to check the ip address the robot's voice seems very odd. Unable to load the Web page for it and cannot connect to the robot in choregraphe. I am however able to connect via SSH.

The robot occasionally plays a little tune, but nothing else.

Does anyone have any ideas? Had the robot less than a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed strange; if you can ssh onto the robot, I would expect the web page and Choregraphe to work. But at least you can troubleshoot a bit from ssh.

It could be that naoqi crashed at boot (though I haven't seen that happen outside of internal development builds); that would explain some of your symptoms (but I would expect the chest button to not work at all). You can check out /var/log/naoqi/tail.naoqi.log for any errors; if NAOqi failed to start the error would be there (or in a file in /var/log/naoqi/servicemanager).

From ssh, you can also try using qicli (which will fail if naoqi has crashed), for example `qicli call ALTextToSpeech.getLanguage` (if you say that the robot's voice is very weird - maybe he's in another language, or pronouncing English word with the French text-to-speech, though I don't see how that could happen).

The robot playing a little tune may just be the robot trying to update his software (but if he gets that far, I'd have expected Choregraphe and the web page to work).

(edit)

If NAOqi works you could also try `qicli call ALAutonomousLife.focusedActivity` and/or `qicli call ALBehaviorManager.getRunningBehaviors` to see which code is running.

You might also want to check if the robot's date is correct (with `date` from ssh, that could explain the webpage issue, and could explain failed updates/synchro at boot).

(edit)

So it seems NAOqi is running but ALAutonomousLife and ALBehaviorManager are missing ... the best place to look is probably in `/var/log/naoqi/servicemanager/system.Naoqi.log`, but this looks like it will be a problem for customer care (unless there's a clear enough error message in there).

Comment: No errors in those files, I tried a simple python script to get the robot to stand up using ALRobotPosture and it stood up without an issue, also within the script I am able to make it walk with ALMotion.

Comment: OK, at least you have naoqi, good to know. I edited a couple more troubleshooting tips into the answer; it could be a date issue, or you could have a rogue behavior running that never finishes correctly (my money is on boot-config/., you can probably find it's logs in the servicemanager folder for more details)

Comment: Date looks like fine, but running the commands you suggested seems a bit worrying... 

```qicli call ALAutonomousLife.focusedActivity
No matching services found for pattern: ALAutonomousLife
ERROR: no services matching the given pattern(s) were found
Innovateteen [err 1] ~ $ qicli call ALBehaviorManager.getRunningBehaviors
No matching services found for pattern: ALBehaviorManager
ERROR: no services matching the given pattern(s) were found```

Comment: OK, looks like an error at start, I edited the answer again.

Comment: Ended up with a factory reset, but would have never found what the problem was without your help. So big thanks there.

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved ! Did you find a specific explanation in the logs, or did you just go "forget it, I'll just factory reset it"?

Comment: Couldn't find anything about autonomous life or behaviour manager crashing, so it was easier to factory reset

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that Nao wouldn't boot entirely when some of its joints are in an unusual position. However, then the chest button would be blinking (white). Having the robot in a crouching position with its hands on the legs helps.